# Extract a single column from a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix generated from the program written in Matlab something like this :

```
     'A'               'B'             'C'              'D'          'E'  
    [       4]    [          1]    [  0.9837]    [      0.9928]    [0.9928]
    [       4]    [          1]    [  0.9995]    [      0.9887]    [0.9995]
    [       4]    [          1]    [  0.9982]    [      0.9995]    [0.9995]
    [       4]    [          1]    [  0.9959]    [      0.9982]    [0.9887]
```

I am trying to extract the column `'D'` without the header 'D'.

I can put into a temporary variable and then extract the column data. But I am wondering, if it could be done in a single step.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tell me the type of your data?  E.g. `whos(foo)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your variable is `data`, then `data(2:end,4)` should do it.

---

Edit:

For example:

```
>> data
data = 
    'A'    'B'    'C'         'D'         'E'     
    [4]    [1]    [0.9837]    [0.9928]    [0.9928]
    [4]    [1]    [0.9995]    [0.9887]    [0.9995] 
    [4]    [1]    [0.9982]    [0.9995]    [0.9995]
    [4]    [1]    [0.9959]    [0.9982]    [0.9887]
>> data(2:end,4)  %Extract the data as a cell array
ans = 
    [0.9928]
    [0.9887]
    [0.9995]
    [0.9982]
>> cell2mat(data(2:end,4))  %Convert to a numeric (typical) array
ans =
    0.9928
    0.9887
    0.9995
    0.9982
```